# How to create a browser tab for WKWebView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to build a new tab function but I am not too sure how I can accomplish this. I am having trouble setting a new or previous WKWebView. And also how do I display an errorView if the url is invalid?

This is what I have so far.

EDIT: I wasn't too sure how to initialize or how to create a invalidurl view. This is kind of like whats going on through my mind

```
class NavigationState : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var url : URL?
    let webView = WKWebView()
}

extension NavigationState : WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.url = webView.url
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    var navigationState : NavigationState
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let webView = navigationState.webView
        webView.navigationDelegate = navigationState
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationState = NavigationState()
    @State var tablist = [NavigationState]
    @State var validurl = true;

    init(){
      //does not work currently
      navigationState.createNewWebView(withRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Button("create new tab"){
               tablist.append(navigationState)
               //create and set new webview
            }
            Text(navigationState.url?.absoluteString ?? "(none)")
           if(validUrl){
            WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!), navigationState: navigationState)
            } else{InvalidURL()}
            HStack {
                Button("Back") {
                    navigationState.webView.goBack()
                }
                Button("Forward") {
                    navigationState.webView.goForward()
                }
              TextField(){onCommit: {    
                navigationState.selectedWebView?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlInput)!))
             }}
            }
        }
         List {
                ForEach(tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                    Button(action: {
                        //set to current webview
                    }, label: {
                        Text(tab.webView.url)
                    })
                }.onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT for the initlization

I added this block of code underneath the NavigationState but I keep getting a blank screen.

```
override init(){
        super.init()
        let wv = WKWebView()
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webViews.append(wv)
        self.selectedWebView = wv
        wv.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively simple implementation (code first, then explanation):

```
class NavigationState : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentURL : URL?
    @Published var webViews : [WKWebView] = []
    @Published var selectedWebView : WKWebView?
    
    @discardableResult func createNewWebView(withRequest request: URLRequest) -> WKWebView {
        let wv = WKWebView()
        wv.navigationDelegate = self
        webViews.append(wv)
        selectedWebView = wv
        wv.load(request)
        return wv
    }
}

extension NavigationState : WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if webView == selectedWebView {
            self.currentURL = webView.url
        }
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @ObservedObject var navigationState : NavigationState
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView  {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        guard let webView = navigationState.selectedWebView else {
            return
        }
        if webView != uiView.subviews.first {
            uiView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
            
            webView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: uiView.bounds.size)
            uiView.addSubview(webView)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationState = NavigationState()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(){
            Button("create new tab"){
                navigationState.createNewWebView(withRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
            }
            Text(navigationState.currentURL?.absoluteString ?? "(none)")
            WebView(navigationState: navigationState)
                .clipped()
            HStack {
                Button("Back") {
                    navigationState.selectedWebView?.goBack()
                }
                Button("Forward") {
                    navigationState.selectedWebView?.goForward()
                }
            }
            
            List {
                ForEach(navigationState.webViews, id: \.self) { tab in
                    Button(action: {
                        navigationState.selectedWebView = tab
                    }) {
                        Text(tab.url?.absoluteString ?? "?")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Instead of trying to store an array of `NavigationState`s, I refactored `NavigationState` to hold an array of web views. The current URL and selected web view are @Published values so that the parent view can see the URL, the selected view, etc.

`WebView` had to be changed significantly since it had to update which `WKWebView` is being shown at any given time.

This is pretty rough-around-the edges code. I'd do more refactoring if it were my own project, but this should get you started.

Regarding showing errors with invalid URLs, that's really a second question and probably needs more clarity (what constitutes an invalid URL? Where is it coming from? Do you mean just if the user enters one (in some part of the UI that you're not describing) or also if they click on an invalid link on the page?)

Comment: Wow thanks for all the help! I'm really new to SwiftUI and I'm learning so much from you :)

Comment: Hi James -- Glad to help. Please mark the answer as correct when you have a chance and (if you haven't) go ahead and give it an upvote if it's helpful

Comment: Done! Also for the invalid url is a textinput that loads  url on commit. I was wondering how I can check if the url is valid or not and deicde if I should display my invalidURLView or my WKWebView. Also is there a way to create a tab on initialization?

Comment: `URL(string:)` returns an optional (right now, you're force unwrapping it with `!`). In your user input you could present an error if it returns `nil`. Regarding the tab, right now, there's an empty array of WebViews. If you make an `init` method for the `NavigationState` you could pre-populate it with an initial value for your first tab (make sure to load the request as well).

Comment: I've been stuck on initializing for a while and I cant seem to figure it out. I keep getting a blank screen. Any ideas why? I updated my post as follow.

Comment: Wrap everything in your `override init()` call below `super.init()` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` block. I'm not exactly sure why it needs that in this case, but it works.