# Trying to implement the ability to launch multiple wkwebview instances to emulate tabbing on a browser

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile-development, uiviewrepresentable

I'm trying to make a very barebones mobile browser to practice swiftui and wkwebview (WKwebview is wrapped in a UIViewRepresentable). However, when trying to implement multiple tabs for the browser I hit an odd error. The default webview works but when pressing the button to add new tabs, I notice that the new webview never actually has it's makeuiview() function run. The new tab just displays the last page that was loaded by the first webview but remains static and can't receive navigation. I'm not sure what would cause a uiviewrepresentable to not run it's makeuiview method. There's more code to this but I posted what I thought mattered most.

Content View
(Where the logic for adding the new tab resides) Refer to Tablist.newTab() function

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


class TabList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabs: [BrowserPage] = [BrowserPage()]
    
    func newTab(){
        tabs.append(BrowserPage())
    }
    
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var tablist: TabList = TabList()
    
    @State var selection = 0
    @State var showTabs: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          
            tablist.tabs[selection]
            Button("next") {
                withAnimation {
                    selection = (selection + 1) % tablist.tabs.count
                }
            }
            Divider()
            Button("add") {
                withAnimation {
                    tablist.newTab()
                    selection = tablist.tabs.count - 1
                    
                }
            }
            Divider()
            Text("\(selection)")
            Text("\(tablist.tabs.count)")
            
        }
        .frame( maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showTabs, content: {
            
        })
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

WebviewModel Class

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class WebViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    var webViewNavigationPublisher = PassthroughSubject<WebViewNavigation, Never>()
    var showWebTitle = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    var showLoader = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
    var valuePublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    var url: String = "https://www.google.com"
    @Published var urltoEdit: String = "https://www.google.com"

}

enum WebViewNavigation {
    case backward, forward, reload, load
}
```

WebsiteView (UIViewRepresentable for WKWebview)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import WebKit

protocol WebViewHandlerDelegate {
    func receivedJsonValueFromWebView(value: [String: Any?])
    func receivedStringValueFromWebView(value: String)
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable, WebViewHandlerDelegate {
   
    func receivedJsonValueFromWebView(value: [String : Any?]) {
        print("JSON value received from web is: \(value)")
    }
    
    func receivedStringValueFromWebView(value: String) {
        print("String value received from web is: \(value)")
    }
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WebViewModel
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.userContentController.add(self.makeCoordinator(), name: "iOSNative")
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        
        //remove after debugging...
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: viewModel.url)!))
        print("UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU " + viewModel.url)
        return webView
    }
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
        var valueSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        var webViewNavigationSubscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil
        var delegate: WebViewHandlerDelegate?
        
        init(_ uiWebView: WebView) {
            self.parent = uiWebView
        }
        
        deinit {
            valueSubscriber?.cancel()
            webViewNavigationSubscriber?.cancel()
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            // Get the title of loaded webcontent
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.title") { (response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error getting title")
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
                guard let title = response as? String else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.parent.viewModel.showWebTitle.send(title)
                
            }
            
            valueSubscriber = parent.viewModel.valuePublisher.receive(on: RunLoop.main).sink(receiveValue: { value in
                let javascriptFunction = "valueGotFromIOS(\(value));"
                webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptFunction) { (response, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error calling javascript:valueGotFromIOS()")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        print("Called javascript:valueGotFromIOS()")
                    }
                }
            })
            
            // Page loaded so no need to show loader anymore
            self.parent.viewModel.showLoader.send(false)
        }
        
        /* Here I implemented most of the WKWebView's delegate functions so that you can know them and
         can use them in different necessary purposes */
        
        func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
            // Hides loader
            parent.viewModel.showLoader.send(false)
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            // Hides loader
            parent.viewModel.showLoader.send(false)
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.parent.viewModel.urltoEdit = webView.url!.absoluteString
            // Shows loader
            parent.viewModel.showLoader.send(true)
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            // Shows loader
            parent.viewModel.showLoader.send(true)
            self.webViewNavigationSubscriber = self.parent.viewModel.webViewNavigationPublisher.receive(on: RunLoop.main).sink(receiveValue: { navigation in
                switch navigation {
                case .backward:
                    if webView.canGoBack {
                        webView.goBack()
                    }
                case .forward:
                    if webView.canGoForward {
                        webView.goForward()
                    }
                case .reload:
                    webView.reload()
                case .load:
                    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.parent.viewModel.url)!))
                    print("IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII  " +  self.parent.viewModel.url)
                }
                
            })
        }
        
        // This function is essential for intercepting every navigation in the webview
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            // Suppose you don't want your user to go a restricted site
            // Here you can get many information about new url from 'navigationAction.request.description'
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Extensions
extension WebView.Coordinator: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        // Make sure that your passed delegate is called
        if message.name == "iOSNative" {
            if let body = message.body as? [String: Any?] {
                delegate?.receivedJsonValueFromWebView(value: body)
            } else if let body = message.body as? String {
                delegate?.receivedStringValueFromWebView(value: body)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BrowserPage View

```
import SwiftUI

struct BrowserPage: View, Identifiable{
  
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = WebViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            URLBarView(viewModel: viewModel)
            
            HStack{
                WebView(viewModel: viewModel)
            }
            
            BottomNavBarView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .padding(.bottom, 25)
           
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be cautious about storing SwiftUI views in Arrays like that -- those views are really meant to be declared in the view hierarchy and their lifecycles managed by the system. The code here is too much for me to dig into right now, but I thought I'd drop a link to a similar question I answered a few weeks ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845387/560942

Comment: If possible, make your codebase more concise so that it only addresses the issue rather than providing your whole codebase.

Comment: @jnpdx Dude that post is already super helpful! I think it's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @wictorious Sorry, haha I'll take better care. Still super new to swiftui so I'm not even sure what's relevant to the problem half the time lol

Comment: @NotASheriff No worries! Treat my previous comment as a piece of advice that will hopefully help you with any of your future questions to get the answers you need as fast as possible.